# formattable::percent doesn't work within ifelse?

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the `percent()` formatter for a `valuebox()` in a shiny app I'm designing... and came across some interesting behavior.

Obviously this works:

```
library(formattable)
a <- 0.2
percent(a)
```

But I need to catch a potential NA, so tried this:

```
ifelse(!is.na(a),percent(a),NA)
```

which  returns the unpercented a (ie 0.2 rather than 20%)! What's going on? Some additional testing:

```
> ifelse(!is.na(a),percent(a),2)
[1] 0.2
> percent(a)
[1] 20.00%
> if(1==1) percent(a)
[1] 20.00%
> ifelse(1==1,percent(a),0)
[1] 0.2
> ifelse(1==1,eval(percent(a)),0)
[1] 0.2
> ifelse(1==1,parse(text = percent(a)),0)
expression(0.2)
> ifelse(1==1,eval(parse(text = percent(a))),0)
[1] 0.2
```

So what's going on?

Full transparency: `percent(NA)` does return `NA`, so I'm not stuck, just curious.

Comment: `ifelse()` strips attributes as pointed out in the examples in `?ifelse`, you have to restore the class attributes.

Comment: You're right, didn't ocurr to me. Added ifelse to title of question for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it outside the ifelse:

```
percent(ifelse(!is.na(a),a,NA))

[1] 20.00%
```

since NA is returned as NA, you can do it for NA:

```
percent(ifelse(!is.na(NA),a,NA))
[1]  NA
```

It also works with a vector with NA and numbers:

```
 percent(ifelse(!is.na(c(0.2,NA)),a,NA))
 [1] 20.00%  NA
```

This also happens in `ifelse` with time formats and a lot more always try to put it outside